# Google Cloud Messaging on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

Has anyone attempted Google Cloud Messaging from Google Glass??  I am guessing there may be an issue with Google Play services, but I have not looked deep into it yet and wanted to see if anyone had tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get GCM working (just tested) using the old deprecated way with gcm.jar from the android sdk. See http://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/gcm-demo/

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this too.  I believe the current GCM will be supported in future, but I cannot confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

As people report, there are no Play Services on Glass: [issue on google-glass-api](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176&q=play%20services&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) tracker.
This means you can't use neither GCM, nor Maps API etc.

What is strange though, if you decompile GlassHome.apk, you can see in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<permission android:name="com.google.glass.home.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

...

<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.google.glass.home" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So, it seems like they've got one.

I digged deeper and found, that inside GlassHome.apk they do have `com.google.android.gcm` package. So, it seems like, they integrated valuable Play Services parts into GlassHome.apk, but they didn't put that API part into the system.

Glass is in the testing stage, so this situation can change in the near future...

Comment: I noticed this too. I also think that they're using GCM to push down the upload/download commands that are triggered when Glass syncs up to the Google Server. It'd be cool to know more about this.